# Min distance from a random point in disk to $n$ i.i.d random points in the same disk

Tags: probability, integration, geometry, geometric-probability

Pick a point $A$ uniformly within a disk of radius 1. Then pick another $n>1$ points $P_1, P_2,..., P_n$ uniformly from the same disk. What is the expected value of $\min\{AP_1, AP_2, ..., AP_n\}$?

Is there a close form distribution of $\min\{AP_1, AP_2, ..., AP_n\}$?

Note that the $AP_i, i = 1, 2, 3...$ should be identically distributed but not necessarily independent because they share $A$ as one endpoint.

One useful thing is that if we just consider $AP_i, i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n$ alone, its distribution is described [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskLinePicking.html).

Also the actual distribution of $\min\{AP_1, AP_2, ..., AP_n\}$ is not the distribution of the minimum length of $n$ uniformly chosen line inside the disk.

Even an answer with $n=2$ would be wonderful.

Comment: I don't see that the $AP_i$ are i.i.d.; specifically, I don't see that they're independent, because they all involve the point $A$. For example, if $AP_1$ is nearly $2$, then $A$ has to be very near the boundary of the disk, and that should influence the probability distribution of $AP_2$. (The $AP_i$ do seem to be conditionally independent, given the location of $A$.)

Comment: Good point. Let me update the statement of the problem.

Comment: Seems like this can be solved, _very_ tediously, by conditioning on the distance $D$ of $A$ from the center, right?  I.e. conditioned on $D=d$, we can calculate the prob of all other points being distance $\ge x$ away by drawing circles.  This leads to the conditional CDF of $\min\{A P_i\}$.  Then you average over $d$ to get the unconditioned CDF.